# Where is scss file

Tags: phpstorm

I use PhpStorm. In new file list I don't have scss file - how to get it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use **Stylesheet** entry -- it's a special "combo" entry for all bundled CSS-related languages. Once invoked you will see a dialog where you can choose what language to use (and it will be remembered for next invocation as well).

Same story for PHP ("PHP Class" entry) and HTML ("HTML File" entry).

**P.S.**
Note, that any custom (user created) File Templates will be listed in that popup menu as usual -- as individual entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add/edit File Templates in PhpStorm:

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/File+Templates+in+PhpStorm